# 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'D'

Tags: python, numpy, math, matrix, jupyter

```
import numpy as np
rowlist = np.array([[0, 2, 3, 4, 5], [0, 0, 0, 3, 2], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [0, 0, 0, 6, 7], [0, 0, 0, 9, 9]])

new_rowlist = []
rows_left = set(range(len(rowlist)))
col_label_list = sorted(rowlist[0].D, key=hash)

for c in col_label_list:
    rows_with_non_zero = [ r for r in rows_left if rowlist[r][c] != 0 ]
    if rows_with_non_zero != []:
        pivot = rows_with_non_zero[0]
        new_rowlist.append(rowlist[pivot])
        rows_left.remove(pivot)

for r in new_rowlist:
    print(r)
```

So i'm following the Coding the Matrix by Philip Klein book lessons and on one of the chapter on Gaussian Elimination, this keeps erroring 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'D'
What I wanted was to be able to sort the matrix called rowlist. Any idea how to overcome this ? im doing this on jupyter notebook if it is of any help
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You typoed and wrote. D in line 6

Comment: If you had read and paid attention to the full error message and stack trace, you would not be asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a typo. There is no `rowlist[0].D`, change the line to the following

```
col_label_list = sorted(rowlist[0], key=hash)
```

Also, maybe from next time as a learning process, try and debug a code yourself by locating which line is causing the error (if you read the error message properly).